# Residuals in a survival analysis

Tags: linear-regression, survival-analysis, jags

I am using JAGS via RJags to estimate **nest survival** of a wader species. I want to estimate the effect of nest age on nest survival (do younger/older nests have a higher survival?), but am not sure whether to model survival as a **linear or quadratic** effect of nest age. Normally in a linear model, I would estimate the linear trend and plot the residuals against it to see if there is some kind of U-shape in the residuals. If so, I would use a quadratic trend.

However, I am not sure what my '**residuals**' of survival would be in a survival analysis?

Are there other ways to determine how I exactly should include age (linear/quadratic)? Or is this only possible by running both models and perform a GOF?

Thank you!